# Is this Perl-related question being closed too hastily?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope, closed-questions, vote-to-close

This question is about to be closed:

- [Perl doesn't include directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239975/perl-doesnt-include-directory)

That's too bad, since:

- Perl scripting is a standard system administration technique and it doesn't make much sense to reject Perl questions unless there's reason to think they're not relevant to that. We keep `bash` scripting questions open, after all.
- In this situation, at least part of the problem appears to have to do with [where the user is installing stuff](https://askubuntu.com/a/239983/22949). That's clearly on the system operation/administration side of the line.
- We can probably answer this, and Stack Overflow probably doesn't want it.

It's not that I think closing this question is an unusually great wrong. But if we can interpret and answer it in a way that's on-topic, we shouldn't be closing it.

(And if it's closed, we should reopen it.)

If it *turns out* nobody can answer it or the issue is sufficiently abstract or esoteric that it's not a good fit for Ask Ubuntu, *then* it can be closed. I see no reason not to give it at least a couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect example of a question that is Ubuntu relevant, is using Perl which is commonly used and has to do with package installation and usage.

The question has been re-opened in the meanwhile.